# How to stay on current tab when a link opens a tab? Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

There are many posts on this, but none seem to have a solution.I think it can be done.

If you have a link with `target='_blank'`, the page will open in a new tab, and it will be in focus.

However, if you press the `CTRL` key when you click that link, the new tab will be in the background.
Therefore, if you can use JavaScript to simulate a `CTRL` press, it should work.

I saw someone post a code trying this, but it was old and used `initMouseEvent` which is depreciated. I think that's why it didn't work.  Could there be a simple way to do this, something like...

`<a href='https://example.com' onclick='...code to simulate CTRL key here...'>CLICK ME</a>`

Comment: not gonna happen

Comment: It's not possible to do what you want on modern browsers, the browsers controls how tabs are opened and gives the control to users in the main browser settings. It's not something a javascript code can do, maybe in some really old browser version so you can use `initMouseEvent`. All this for security reasons, remember all those pages opening several tabs until your browser crashed just to gain more visits? I don't miss those days for sure :P

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make this work in modern browsers anymore. All the methods that existed are deprecated and should not be used.